# check the checklist with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, validation

I want to check that the checklists are not null with jquery or javascript
and if check lists are not null then dont show *please enter product*

```
@model Fruit_Shop.Models.ViewModels.CreateDiscountViewModel`

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" id="CreateDiscountForm">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <p id="inputNull" class="text-danger"></p>
```

There are checklists :

```
            @foreach (var item in @Model.Products)
            {
                <label class="container">
                    @item.ProductName
                    @if (ViewBag.Products != null)
                    {
                        @foreach (var Product in ViewBag.Products as List<Product>@*as List<Product>*@)
                    {
                    @if (Product == item)
                    {
                    
                        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="@item.ProductId" checked="checked">
                    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="@item.ProductId">
                    
                    }
                    }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input type="checkbox" name="products" value="@item.ProductId">

                    }
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <br />
            }

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" id="DiscountSubmit" onclick="validate()" class="btn btn-primary" /> //submit button
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

And I tested:

```
section Scripts {
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            if ($('input[name = "products"]').value() == null)
            {
                document.getElementById('inputNull').innerHTML = "";

            }
        });

        $('#CreateDiscountForm').submit(function(e){
            if ($('input[name = "products"]').value() != null)
            {
                document.getElementById('inputNull').innerHTML = "please enter product";
                e.preventDefault();

            }
        });

    </script>
}
```

But everything I did did not work

P.S: this project is in asp.net core and
if I wrote the text badly, I'm sorry because this is my first question:)

Comment: Any specific reason not to use ASP.NET Core validation controls? You can more details here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040

Comment: Because I want to customize the inputs

Comment: I removed the jQuery Validate tag because it looks like you're writing validation from scratch without the jQuery Validate plugin.

Comment: Yes, for some reason I can not use the jquery validate tag
so I Can't do this without a jquery validate tag?

Comment: Did you able to extract the value of `input[name = "products"]').value()`?